# Explanation about incrementation and assignment

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some question about how work the incrementation in C++;

I have seen many subjects about the value of i++ or ++i but not when used for an assignment.

I have a `boost::container::flat_map<std::string, std::string*> param_;` and `boost::sregex_token_iterator ii` who contain [name, test].

If I was working with a char* I would do something like

```
param[*ii] = new std::string(*(ii + 1));
```

But it's not working so I have done something like:

```
 std::string tmp = *(ii++);
 this->param_[tmp] = new std::string(*(ii));
```

and I am getting the correct output:

```
 name : test;
```

But when I try to do it on one line, I am not getting the correct output:
First I have tried:

```
this->param_[*(ii++)] = new std::string(*(ii));
```

but I get:
   `id : id;`

and then by mistake I have tried:
   `this->param_[*(++ii)] = new std::string(*(ii));`

and I get:
   `test : name` 
I understand why I get 'test' in first but not why I get 'name' in second since I have already incremented ii?

To display the map I do simply a

```
 for (auto ii = this->param_.begin(); ii != this->param_.end();++ii)
    std::cout << ii->first << ":" << *ii->second << std::endl;
```

Comment: KISS: Just don't do several things at once (unless it's an unavoidable atomic operation).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increment decrement operator mystery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264561/increment-decrement-operator-mystery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(ii + 1)` doesn't work because `operator+` is only supported by RandomAccessIterators and `sregex_token_iterator` is only a ForwardIterator.

The `ii++` version has undefined behaviour because you are reading and writing from the same variable in a single expression.

If you really wanted to do it in one statement you could do:

```
param[*ii] = new std::string(*++boost::sregex_token_iterator(ii));
```

This makes a copy of the iterator and increments the copy, not the original, but it isn't clear what it's doing and it would be much better to just split it into multiple statements:

```
boost::sregex_token_iterator next = ii;
++next;
param[*ii] = new std::string(*next);
```

Answer (score 1):

> since I have already incremented ii?

You seem to be making unfounded assumptions about order of evaluation in C++.  You have not *already* incremented `ii`, it is being incremented elsewhere in the same statement, but the read and write of `ii` are unordered with respect to each other, giving undefined behavior.

The only thing that can be said about your expression is that function arguments are evaluation before the function is called (in this case, the `operator*` iterator dereference function and the map `operator[]` access function), but not the order in which the arguments are evaluated.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess there is no way to force the order in which the elements are evaluated and do the operation in 1 line.